# Can someone explain MySeriesHelper in influxdb, there is not much information availabe and i am new to this

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

Currently, I am writing datapoints using `client.write_points`, but i want to write datapoints in batches. How should I proceed? Here is my code.

```
def send_measurement_to_influx(influx_measurement_payload, client):
  try:

    client.write_points(influx_measurement_payload)
    pass
except Exception as e:
    logging.exception("Error while sending measurement {} to influx host", format(str(influx_measurement_payload)),
                      e, exc_info=True)

def timeit(**kwargs):
 def timeit_helper(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()

        if('metric_name' in kwargs):
            metric_name = kwargs['metric_name']
            client = get_influx_client()
            if(client is not None):
              influx_measurement_payload = [(generate_influx_payload(metric_name, method.__name__,
                                                                   method.__module__, (te-ts) * 1000))]

              send_measurement_to_influx(influx_measurement_payload, client)



        if 'log_time' in kwargs:
            name = kwargs.get('log_name', method.__name__.upper())
            kwargs['log_time'][name] = int((te - ts) * 1000)
        else:
            logging.info('%r  %2.2f ms' % \
                         (method.__name__, (te - ts) * 1000))
        return result
    return timed
return timeit_helper
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd pass the batch size in with the `write_points` call.

`client.write_points(influx_measurement_payload, batch_size=1000)`

Docs
https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html?highlight=batch#influxdb.InfluxDBClient.write_points

Here they suggest that if the payload contains more than 5000 datapoints you might want to start using the batch option. So batch_size=5000 is something like an upper limit but that would depend on the usecase and is better to derive a good batch_size through benchmarking it.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/guides/writing_data/#writing-points-from-a-file